# Getting error when I try iterate through an immutable.js

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following code:

reduce.js:

```
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';

const initialState = fromJS({
  "ff0bce4-ef2e-4eb6-b7b4-2f759d6ee0bb": {
    "id": "8ff0bce4-ef2e-4eb6-b7b4-2f759d6ee0bb",
    "type": "course",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Wordpress"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://api.dev.course.com/api/v1/course/8ff0bce4-ef2e-4eb6-b7b4-2f759d6ee0bb"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "modules": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://api.dev.course.com/api/v1/course/8ff0bce4-ef2e-4eb6-b7b4-2f759d6ee0bb/relationships/modules",
          "related": "http://api.dev.course.com/api/v1/course/8ff0bce4-ef2e-4eb6-b7b4-2f759d6ee0bb/modules"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cd65128e-c89e-4a1a-8022-148e6bc673d2": {
    "id": "cd65128e-c89e-4a1a-8022-148e6bc673d2",
    "type": "course",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "Symfony"
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "http://api.dev.course.com/api/v1/course/cd65128e-c89e-4a1a-8022-148e6bc673d2"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "modules": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://api.dev.course.com/api/v1/course/cd65128e-c89e-4a1a-8022-148e6bc673d2/relationships/modules",
          "related": "http://api.dev.course.com/api/v1/course/cd65128e-c89e-4a1a-8022-148e6bc673d2/modules"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

function list(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default list;
```

courseList.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class CourseListContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          {
            this.props.courses.map((course, s) => {
              <div>test1</div>

            })
          }
        </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  const common = state.get('common');

  return {
    courses: common.get('courseList'),
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CourseListContainer);
```

When I try to iterate the courses I get this warning:
**Warning: Using Maps as children is unsupported and will likely yield unexpected results. Convert it to a sequence/iterable o...**

So, I tried to use different ways to iterate such as: valueSeq(), entrySeq... but none of them works. I didn't get any warning in this case, but I didn't see "asdasdasd" twice. In this case it's like courses is emprty but is not becasue I check the console and I can see the information.

Answer (score 2):

`Immutable.Map#map` returns an `Immutable.Map` so you are giving react a Map of children. You should be able to do:

[courses.values().map()](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/667#issuecomment-150089997)

Or,

[courses.valueSeq().map()](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/issues/667#issuecomment-150120670)

Or, you may also use keys:

```
Object.keys(courses).map()
```

Comment: I get an error If I do courses.values().map() or courses.valueSeq().map().
Uncaught TypeError: this.props.trainings.values(...).map is not a function
With Object.keys(courses).map() I didn't get the values

Comment: I tried to do the same in compoentWillMount and is working.
componentWillMount() {
    console.log("componentWillMount");
    this.props.courses.map((course) => {
      console.log("ss");
      console.log(course);
      return course;
    });
  }.

Comment: the problem is that doesn't work inside of the render.

Comment: ok, it's working. I have forgotten to add the return inside of the return

Comment: For me entrySeq()

Comment: Glad, it helped.